# How to filter using Pandasql

Tags: pandas, pandasql

I have below query to select rows as per the `where` condition;

```
top4_hr_visits = pysqldf("SELECT room_name, hour, COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS user_cnt FROM user_data       
                     WHERE room_name ='Emilio's Room' OR room_name= 'Azalea's Room'
                     GROUP BY room_name, hour;")
```

But I am getting following error;
`OperationalError: near "s": syntax error`
Is there a way to properly escape it? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Single quotes are escaped by doubling them up**, just as you've shown us in your example replace single quote by adding another one

```
"SELECT room_name, hour, COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS user_cnt FROM user_data       
                     WHERE room_name ='Emilio''s Room' OR room_name= 'Azalea''s Room'
                     GROUP BY room_name, hour;"
```

Comment: appreciate your help.is that always true(i.e. doubling quotes) for all versions of SQL?

Comment: No for all versions I dont think, but for the version that I tested it is working, I mean for pandasql should work